# How to exclude some pakages from code coverage report using android and jacoco

Tags: android, code-coverage, android-jacoco

I try to exclude some packages from the jacoco report but I don't find any documentation about doing that.

I tried that, but doesn't work:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        jacoco {
            afterEvaluate {
                classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                    fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**/*databinding/**/*.*')
                }))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2` and `org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.8`.

Do you know how to exclude packages from jacoco report?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any "packaged" solution to solve my issue, so to move forward, I create my own gradle task:

```
task jacocoDebugUnitTestCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    group = "Verification"
    description = "Creates JaCoCo test coverage report"
    reports {
        html.required = true
        xml.required = true
    }
    classDirectories.from = fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug/transformDebugClassesWithAsm/dirs/my/package/app",
            excludes: [
                    '**/databinding/*',
                    '**/Dagger*',
                    '**/Hilt*',
                    '**/DataBinding*',
                    '**/DataBinder*',
                    '**/*_*'
            ]
    )
    sourceDirectories.from = ['src/main/java/my.package.app']
    executionData.from = fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir",
            includes: ["outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec"])
}
```

Running `./gradlew jacocoDebugUnitTestCoverageReport` generate a coverage report without excluded packages.

If you know a better solution, I would appreciate your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a gradle task with section `afterEvaluate` to exclude the package and all classes within from the test coverage evaluation. This is important to exclude the test coverage for classes which are data models or generated class

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'com/demo/packagetobeexcluded/**')
        }))
    }
}
test.finalizedBy(jacocoTestReport)
```