Exclude hilt generated classes from android unit test coverage report
When generating coverage report in Android unit test by selection option "Run **test with coverage", we see a lot of hilt generated classes being added to the report giving us wrong coverage info. How to exclude those files?

does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76449686/how-to-exclude-some-pakages-from-code-coverage-report-using-android-and-jacoco help?

I am not using jacaco, so its not helping
